# How do i use wild card in (where in . . .)command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Select id, dim, name, others
from Table1
where dim in ('15-12 a2 _z', '15-12 b2 _z')
```

Table  consist of 20k values.
I have used _ as a wild card in the code, I think it is not allowed, in this case it is considered as character.
Is there any way to get the desired solution?

Comment: You can't use wildcards with the `IN` operator. Wildcards are only applicable with `LIKE` or `PATINDEX`.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE dim LIKE '15-12 a2 %z' OR dim LIKE '15-12 b2 %z'`

SQL Server has minimal capabilities for wildcard usage, so that's pretty much all you're going to be able to do.

Comment: I have tested this option but no results. :(

Comment: This is how you do it. Whether or not you get results is a different story.  Maybe you don't have any records where dim matches that pattern.

Comment: Sure i have records with dim '15-12 a2 12z', '15-12 a2 18z', '15-12 a2 22z' and so on

Comment: Sorry then, something else is going on that you haven't told us.  This should be a pretty simple case.

Answer (score 0):

% is a wildcard for 1 or more characters.
_ is for a single character...Hence, as Rory has already said....this shows it working....

```
create table #t(
f1 varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #t
SELECT '15-12 a2 12z'
UNION all SELECT '15-12 a2 18z'
UNION ALL SELECT'15-12 a2 22z'

SELECT 'PERCENT WILDCARD', * FROM #t 
WHERE f1 LIKE '15-12 a2 %z' OR f1 LIKE '15-12 b2 %z'


SELECT 'UNDERSCORE WILDCARD', * FROM #t 
WHERE f1 LIKE '15-12 a2 __z' OR f1 LIKE '15-12 b2 __z'

DROP TABLE #t
```